# Fluent nhibernate map list of items

Tags: nhibernate, list, nhibernate-mapping, bag

I have a class "Company" which has a list of "Operator"

```
public class Company
{
   public IList<Opertator> Operators {get; set; }
   public Int32 Id {get; set;}
}

public class Operator {
   public Int32 Id {get; set; }
  public Company Company {get; set; }
}
```

When I mapped as follows:

```
public class CompanyMapping : ClassMap<Company>
    {
        public ProductMapping() : base()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id, "CompanyId").GeneratedBy.Native();
            HasMany(x => x.Operators);
         }
    }

public class OperatorMapping : ClassMap<Operator>
{
    public OperatorMapping() 
    {
          Id(x => x.Id);
          Reference(x => x.Company);
    }
}
```

I have a UI where user can add operators and remove operators by checking boxes.
in c# code, I query the stored company, and add to the list, or remove from the list.
then send SaveOrUpdate.
My problem is when I add one more operator to existing company, and save/Update, the NHibernate is deleting the whole list, and reinster them again.

I don't want to do that.
Can I have it, that NHibernate will detect the changed items (new items from the list, and insert them, and determine the deleted item and delete them)?

I tried change the mapping to have in the company mapping

```
HasMany(x => x.Operators).Inverse();
```

but it end up not deleting at all.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Inverse says that the Operator is responsible for the association and you have to set it when adding an `Operator` to the Company

```
public class Company
{
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Opertator> Operators {get; private set; }

    public void Add(Opertator operator)
    {
        Operators.Add(operator);
        operator.Company = this;
    }

    public Company()
    {
        Operators = new List<Operator>();
    }
}

// and

HasMany(x => x.Operators).Inverse();

// use it like

company.Add(new Operator()); // instead of company.Operators.Add(new Operator());
```